# asp MVC 3 Cookie disabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, session-cookies

I have and MVC 3 application that uses Forms authentication provided by asp.net Membership. I set inside web.config inside forms tag `cookieless="AutoDetect"`.

If I disable cookies on my browser I can get normally logged but after a `RedirectToAction("myAction")` I get login page again losing my authetication!
Can I use my MVC application in a cookieless browser? If so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the controller and action name as per

[ASP.Net MVC 2 Forms Authentication cookieless = "UseUri" while submit authorization fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895819/asp-net-mvc-2-forms-authentication-cookieless-useuri-while-submit-authorizat)

and
http://forums.asp.net/t/1561291.aspx

I see a post that it doesn't seem to be supported, but give this a try. In your case its a redirect so not even sure it will show up there. If it doesn't work I have to assume the implementation isn't there. Why cookieless btw? This was intended for lack of cookie suppor t on mobile devices which now pretty much all support cookies so I would caution against its use.

Comment: For example, cookies from other domains are prohibited in frames in IE browser.